# Which NLP library has the most mature Chinese language models?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to do some NLP on Simplified Chinese texts (needing to extract sentence structure and to do named entity recognition).  I've used spaCy previously for English texts, but I see the [notes on the Chinese models](https://github.com/howl-anderson/Chinese_models_for_SpaCy/blob/master/README.en-US.md) suggest they are a work in progress, and the NER extraction accuracy has been poor for the examples I've tried.

Which NLP library has the most mature pre-built Chinese language models? Ideally Python based.

Answer (score 1):

There are no common libraries that support high quality named entity recognition for Chinese.

Other options include [Information-Extraction-Chinese](https://github.com/crownpku/Information-Extraction-Chinese) on GitHub or adapting a [paper with code](https://paperswithcode.com/task/chinese-named-entity-recognition).

Comment: spaCy and Stanza's Chinese models both state they do NER, and I've confirmed that spaCy does NER, but badly. https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/available_models.html https://spacy.io/models/zh

Answer (score 0):

After evaluating a few libraries against Chinese texts:

- spaCy's POS tagging has poor accuracy
- Stanford Stanza's POS tagging is generally good, but often incorrectly identifies words in single word sentences as POS = "PUNCT"
- NLTK does not natively handle Chinese POS tagging
- CoreNLP has good POS tagging accuracy and does a reasonable job of NER tagging.

I suspect this is more about the quality of the pre-built models than the libraries themselves.